# How did Glauber come up with his definition of non-classical states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space

In their [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.140.B676), Titulaer and Glauber state

> The results [...] are derived only for fields with
> positive-definite P functions. Those are, in fact, precisely the quantum fields which may be described in a
> natural way as possessing classical analogs.

The $P$ function mentioned here is the [Glauber-Sudarshan P representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber%E2%80%93Sudarshan_P_representation). In the paper the authors shows that for $P \ge 0$ correlation functions follow a hierarchy of inequalities and, apparently, from these inequalities it follows that the state described by $P$ has a classical analog.

However, I fail to see how one can draw this conclusion, especially since this point is not further elucidated. So what is the argument I am missing or is there a better reference to see that positive $P$ functions correspond to classical states (or the often stated converse: negative $P$ indicate non classical behaviour)?

Comment: You do appreciate "classical analog" states is a synonym for  just generalized coherent states ("Schrodinger wave packets"), right?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I appreciate that this was new to me. Still, I fail to see that generalised coherent states necessarily produce positive P's and I still don't see the connection that is made in the paper, or more generally why Glauber defines "positive P are classical".

Comment: W Schleich’s textbook has a good review of this fact.